# Two Ports positions in JointJS

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I'm new to JointJS and I'm having trouble working with door positions.

I have 3 ports, 1 of type, 'Out', and 2 of type 'in'.

I'd like to change the position of only one of the 'in' type ports, but I'm not getting it.

Here I leave an image and a link of the code. Thanks for the help right away.

```
var m1 = new joint.shapes.devs.Model({
    position: { x: 50, y: 50 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
    inPorts: ['in1','in2'],
    outPorts: ['out'],
    ports: {
      groups: {
        'in': {
          position: "top",
          attrs: {
            '.port-body': {
              r: "6",
              fill: 'blue',
              magnet: 'passive'
            },
            '.port-label': {
              fill: "transparent"
            }
          }
        },
        'out': {
          position: "bottom",
          portLabelMarkup: '<text fill="yellow"/>',
          attrs: {
            '.port-body': {
              r: "6",
              fill: 'red'
            },
            '.port-label': {
              fill: "transparent"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    attrs: {
        '.label': { text: 'node 1', 'ref-x': .5, 'ref-y': .2 },
        rect: { fill: 'LightGrey', rx: 15, ry: 15 }
    }
}).addTo(graph);
```

[Link of the code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMJxrZ?editors=0010)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest NOT to use the shapes based on the `devs.Model` as it's a legacy implementation of ports. Since the JointJS v1.0 you can add ports to any shape.

for example:

```
var m1 = new joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle({
    position: { x: 425, y: 60 },
    size: { width: 200, height: 100 },
    ports: {
        groups: {
            'in': {
                position: {
                    name: 'top',
                    args: { dr: 0, dx: 0, dy: -9 }
                },
            }
        },
        items: [
            { group: 'in', args: { y: -10 }, id: 'portId'}
        ]

    }
});
```

Port positions is set using the layout functions. In your example there is the `top` layout - it means port positions is computed using the `joint.layout.Port.top` implementation. You can override the result using the `args` properties on a port:

```
// set args on newly added
m1.addPort({ group: 'in', args: { y: -20 } });
// update existing
m1.portProp('portId', 'args/y', -20)
```

for more information see the layout docs: https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.2/joint.html#layout.Port